# Wifi audio extender

Tags: wifi, airplay

I need to replace an old airport express which I use purely to get audio from my computer over to where my stereo system is. It also acts as a wifi extender. Other than airport, what other modem/router/accesspoint hardware can I consider?

Comment: I don't know of any non-Apple routers with airplay capabilities - at least none that are as easy to use. I'd get an old express or extreme on eBay. They're pretty cheap (<$30).

Comment: I found this one: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KGGHYWK/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A4UCFL9LU89NR Does anyone know anything about it?

Comment: It says it's airplay compatible, so after set up you should be able to find it where your express used to be

Answer (score -1):

I found this product which I think satisfies my requirements: [D-Link DCH-M225 Wi-Fi Audio Extender](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KGGHYWK). I will let you know once I get it!